# Builtin round() function changes its behaviour with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the code below:

```
>>> help(round)
round(number, ndigits=None)
    Round a number to a given precision in decimal digits.
    The return value is an integer if ndigits is omitted or None.  Otherwise
    the return value has the same type as the number.  ndigits may be negative.
>>> type(t)
<class 'numpy.float64'>
>>> type(round(t))
<class 'numpy.float64'>
>>> t=2.3
>>> type(t)
<class 'float'>
>>> type(round(t))
<class 'int'>
```

The type of the return value of `round` should be `int`, (or maybe `numpy.int64`).
I see that `numpy` has a `round` function with this behaviour:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> type(np.round(1.1))
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

So it seems that the builtin `round` function is magically replaced by `numpy.round`, when it applies to a numpy data. How is it possible ?

Comment: Not necessarily. It clearly says the return type is the same as the input type.

Comment: There are various issues open on the NumPy bug tracker that discuss this. For example, https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11810, https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3511